# get_the_tags with separator control?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, tags

I'm building a function in theme options to give the site owner more control over the post's "Tags" collection that I display at the bottom of each post page. Specifically, whether to add anchor text to them or not.

However, since none of the available functions: the_tags(), get_the_tags(), etc will create an unanchored list with separators, I'm left to roll my own method (unless, as I'm hoping, I'm missing something)

In the 1st part of the code branch below, once we determine the post has tags and the user has chosen to display them without links, I'm manually creating the tag list and adding a comma separator. How can I remove the separator from the last tag or from a single tag when that condition exists? (or better, is there a core method that will do it for me?)

```
function my_get_tags(){
    $unlinkTags = get_option('my_unlinkTags');
    $gotTags = get_the_tags();
    if(!$gotTags) return;

    //we got tags, lets create a wrapper
    echo '<div><span class="tags">';

    //no anchors and a separator? have to roll our own
    if($unlinkTags)
        {
        foreach($gotTags as $tag) {echo $tag->name . ', ';}
        }
    //they want anchors, easy peasy, use get tags
    else
        {
        echo the_tags('', ', ', '');
        }
    echo '</span></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$output = array();

foreach($gotTags as $tag)
    $output[] = $tag->name;

echo implode(',', $output);
```